# Pandas combine multiple pivot tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have `df1`, `piv1`, and, `piv2` below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'R': [1, 2], 'S': ['s1', 's2'], 'G1': ['g1a', 'g1b'], 'G2': ['g2a', 'g2b']})

df1
    R   S   G1  G2
0   1   s1  g1a g2a
1   2   s2  g1b g2b

piv1 = df1.pivot_table(index=(['S']), columns=(['G1']), aggfunc=({'R': 'mean'}))

piv1
        R
G1  g1a g1b
S       
s1  1.0 NaN
s2  NaN 2.0

piv2 = df1.pivot_table(index=(['S']), columns=(['G2']), aggfunc=({'R': 'mean'}))

piv2
        R
G2  g2a g2b
S       
s1  1.0 NaN
s2  NaN 2.0
```

Instead of `piv1` and `piv2`, I am trying to make `piv3` which would look like below. Any ideas? Ideally I'd like to create `piv3` directly from `df1` (i.e. not needing to create `piv1` and `piv2` and then combine them).

```
piv3
S   g1a  g1b  g2a  g2b
s1  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
s2  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.melt` and `pivot_table`:

```
df1.melt(['S','R']).pivot_table(index='S',columns='value',values='R').rename_axis(None)
```

---

```
value  g1a  g1b  g2a  g2b
s1     1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
s2     NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the index column title `value` so that it's just blank instead?

Comment: @CHRD you can chain a `.rename_axis(None,axis=1)` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
s=df1.melt(['R','S']).groupby(['S','value']).R.mean().unstack()
Out[63]: 
value  g1a  g1b  g2a  g2b
S                        
s1     1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
s2     NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant answer:

```
piv3 = piv1.copy()
piv3[piv2.columns] = piv2

Out[17]: 
      R               
G1  g1a  g1b  g2a  g2b
S                     
s1  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
s2  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
```